# Angular Directive link function click does not get called in Jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jasmine

I have an Angular Directive that closes a modal window by detecting a click outside the component that opened the modal:

```
module showmodal {
'use strict';

export class ShowModal implements ng.IDirective {
    restrict: string = 'A';
    scope: any = {
        showModal: '=showModal'
    };
    link: ng.IDirectiveLinkFn = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attributes: ng.IAttributes) => {
        function handler(): void {
            if ((element[0] !== event.target) && (0 === element.find(event.target).length)) {
                scope.$apply((): void => {
                    scope['showModal'] = false;
                });
            }
        }
        this.$document.on('click', handler);
        scope.$on('$destroy', () => {
            this.$document.off('click', handler);
        });
    };

    constructor(
        private $document: ng.IDocumentService,
        private $parse: ng.IParseService) {
    }

    static instance(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        const factory: ng.IDirectiveFactory = (
            $document: ng.IDocumentService,
            $parse: ng.IParseService): ng.IDirective => {
            return new ShowModal($document, $parse);
        };
        factory.$inject = [
            '$document',
            '$parse'
        ];
        return factory;
    }
}
angular.module('showmodal')
    .directive('showModal', ShowModal.instance());
}
```

Implemented as:

```
<div ng-init="showModal=false" show-modal="showModal">
    <input type="text" class="input" ng-click="showModal=!showModal" />
    <div class="modal" ng-show="showModal">The modal</div>
</div>
```

The code works as expected. The user clicks on the input which sets showModal to true showing the modal and when they click anywhere else on the page, the directive detects the click, decides if it fired outside the element and if so, sets showModal to false, hiding the modal.

I am attempting to test the directive. The click event does not get fired from the Jasmine test. This is what I have so far:

```
module showmodal {
'use strict';

var element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery;
var scope: any;

describe('ShowModal directive', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        angular.mock.module('showmodal');
        angular.mock.inject(($rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService, $compile: ng.ICompileService) => {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            var html: ng.IAugmentedJQuery =
                angular.element('<div class="click" ng-click=""></div><div ng-init="showModal=false" show-modal="showModal"><input type="text" class="input" ng-click="showModal=!showModal" /><div class="modal" ng-show="showModal">The modal</div></div>');
            element = $compile(html)(scope);
            scope.$apply();
        });
    });
    iit('should set showModal to false', () => {
        expect(scope.showModal).toBeFalsy();
        element.find('.input').triggerHandler('click');
        scope.$apply();
        expect(scope.showModal).toBeTruthy();
        element.find('.click').triggerHandler('click'); <- element is clicked but does not fire the click event in the directive.
        scope.$apply();
        expect(scope.showModal).toBeFalsy(); <- fails here
    });
});
}
```

In theory, the test clicks the input which sets showModal to true (this works). It then clicks the div with class 'click' which should fire the click event in the directive but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this myself by creating a click on $document as opposed to clicking a div:

```
 var element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery;
var scope: any;
var document: ng.IDocumentService;

describe('ShowModal directive', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        angular.mock.module('showmodal');
        angular.mock.inject((
            $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService,
            $compile: ng.ICompileService,
            $document: ng.IDocumentService) => {

            document = $document;
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            var html: ng.IAugmentedJQuery =
                angular.element(
                    '<div ng-init="showModal=false" show-modal="showModal">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="input" ng-click="showModal=!showModal" />' +
                    '<div class="modal" ng-show="showModal">The modal</div>' +
                    '</div>');
            element = $compile(html)(scope);
            scope.$apply();
        });
    });
    it('should set showModal from false to true then back to false', () => {
        expect(scope.showModal).toBeFalsy();
        element.find('.input').triggerHandler('click');
        expect(scope.showModal).toBeTruthy();
        document.click();
        expect(scope.showModal).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```